# when ratating a view, MotionEvent#getX getY return abnoral value

Tags: android, motionevent

I customized a rectangle view which can be ratated when touching its top left corner, also it can be moved when touching its center position. when moving the view after ratating it, MotionEvent#getX or MotionEvent#getY would return unnormal value.

[image]

While I just move it,the returned value of  MotionEvent#getX or MotionEvent#getY is normal.

[image]

The variable definition in srceenshot:

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      mDownX = event.getX();
      mDownY = event.getY();
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      float eventMoveX = event.getX();
      float eventMoveY = event.getY();
```

Appreciate it!

Comment: "which can be rotated"?

Comment: Yeah, the view can be rotated by touching one of its corner and moving finger on the screen.